# Trigger action immediately after connection is available

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to trigger an action once the connection is available. There are solutions available which allows manually checking internet connection. One way i find is using NSTimer to check for internet connection during fixed intervals. But is it the most effective way to check for it? if Not, What is the right solution for this?

Comment: Why not just use `Reachability`status and perform action when status changes?

Comment: Problem is how to continuously check the Reachability status.

Comment: If you have added the observer properly then it will change the status & prompt you as soon as network status changes

Comment: There! This is what I am looking for. Can you provide links or related examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [reachability code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) provided by apple.In [appdelegate.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_ReachabilityAppDelegate_m.html) you can see this method.It will notify the network change.Work on it

```
//Called by Reachability whenever status changes.
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here how you can register the observer and listen to it, Your application will be listening to `kReachabilityChangedNotification` & prompt you whenever status of network changes.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityHasChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];



-(void) reachabilityHasChanged:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");


            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");


            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");


            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This looks like a simpler solution for NSNovice like me.:)

Comment: I added the first 3 lines in your solution to my AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWith.. and added an alerview in ReachabilityHasChanged-Not Reachable. But somehow its not calling the method.:|

Comment: download the [Reachability Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) and follow how it has been done. you should actually add observer within the ApplicationDidBecome Active also.